# Making a directory accessible to get files in it through url

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I have a directory containing images. Images are added in it at any time, during runtime. I want to make these files visible through some url.

I tried to put this directory in wildfly webapp directory. But the images added at runtime are not visible.

How to make this directory accessible.

Comment: You could find a detailed answer this link [how-can-i-serve-static-resources-from-outside-a-war-on-wildfly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426082/how-can-i-serve-static-resources-from-outside-a-war-on-wildfly/34433166#34433166).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a file handler in the undertow subsystem and map it to a URL. In CLI you'd execute something similar to the following to commands.

```
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=handler/file=images:add(directory-listing=true, follow-symlink=true, path=/path/to/image/directory)
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/location=\/images:add(handler=images)
```

That would list all the images on `localhost:8080/images`. You can turn off the directory listing and/or use a complete image URL to see the specific image.

Answer (score 0):

In your `deployments`, create a new directory with the `.war` extension, as:

```
$WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/deployments/images.war/
```

This is an "exploded" deployment, and any new images added there can be reached via:

```
http://localhost:8080/images/
```

Comment: Then I will not be able to dynamically add images into it through servlets etc...

Comment: Why not? Just write to that directory. Or use symlinks if your server is a *nix.